# Quickcheck: generate a string made of chars from a given pool

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck

```
propertyForStringsFromMyCharPool :: String -> Bool
-- implementation

main = T.quickCheck propertyForStringsFromMyCharPool
```

Right now QuickCheck generates all kinds of strings, but I want to test my property only for strings from my pool of characters.

My output now is:

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 3 tests and 2 shrinks):    
"-"
```

But it is not a real failure because `-` is not included in my charset and no string containing it should have been generated in the first place.

---

- I have tried to read the read [the docs of  QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html) but they are very abstract and hard, I did not find a sloution.
- I have seen [a solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934506/haskell-quickcheck-how-to-generate-only-printable-strings) but it seems so much code for what looks like an easy problem, that I fear it is over-engineered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use

```
elements :: [a] -> Gen a
```

in combination with

```
listOf :: Gen a -> Gen [a]
```

so your `String` generator could look something like

```
vowels :: Gen String
vowels = listOf (elements "aeiou")
```

Comment: I just saw your code in the pastebin - please name your functions `encode`/`decode` and have some `newtype`-aliases for `Brainf***` and `OoO` for `String` to go along with it.

Comment: I am in fact worried about the quality of the code I wrote. I would be grateful if you could give me some advice at Codereview -> [Convert oOo to Brainfuck and viceversa](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121393/convert-ooo-to-brainfuck-and-viceversa)